# Horizontal Slide Out Menu does not work in Firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, firefox, drop-down-menu

I was trying to implement a Horizontal Slide Out Menu from this [Tutorial](http://tympanus.net/codrops/2013/05/17/horizontal-slide-out-menu/). When I checked out the [Demo](http://tympanus.net/Blueprints/HorizontalSlideOutMenu/), I found out that the menu works fine in Chrome, Opera and even IE but not in Firefox. I tried digging into the code, but could not find the incompatible code. Can someone please point out the piece of code that causes it to not run in Firefox?

Thanks.

Comment: As i checked this is Working in Firefox...

Comment: I am using the latest Firefox 29, but the menu does not work on my firefox.

Comment: the menu works fine on firefox

Comment: Which Firefox version are you using?

Comment: I am using firefox 28.

Comment: @PradeepPansari Just to be sure, you checked http://tympanus.net/Blueprints/HorizontalSlideOutMenu by clicking on "Lovely Spirits" or "Delicious Beverages" Drop Down and the Drop Down Menu appeared?

Comment: I just reset my Firefox and the menu works fine now ! May be it must have been due to me  tampering with the about:config preferences. Anyways thanks guys for trying to help out !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Initially the Horizontal Slide Out Menu was not working on my Firefox 29, nothing happened when clicked on the drop down links in the menu.

Then I [Reset](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/reset-firefox-easily-fix-most-problemshttps://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/reset-firefox-easily-fix-most-problems) my Firefox and tested the [Demo](http://tympanus.net/Blueprints/HorizontalSlideOutMenu/) again and now the drop down menu works fine! My guess is that the about:config preferences must have been changed before and after resetting the preferences were reset to default and so the drop down menu started showing up. I may be entirely wrong, if some one knows the right reason please feel to free to correct me.